# Android: Add a very long TextView to a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, textview

I am trying to add a very long text (Glgamesh's epic) in a fragment.

My xml version:

```
<LinearLayout.LayoutParams xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".viewOne">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/epica"
        android:text=" **I WILL INSERT HERE THE WHOLE TEXT?**" />

</LinearLayout.LayoutParams>
```

also what's the java part?
do I have to rewrite the content in setText? Can I recall it just by ID?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dynamic_linearlayout);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.epica);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Hey, thanks!

Comment: your question is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: `I am trying to` **and the problem is** <-- continue this

Comment: I am trying to [header of the question: add a very long text to a fragment] and the problem is [check content of the post]
--really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make and APP like a book with pages you can't do it like this. You have to create a database to store the content of each page. Then you can load page by page to the text view when user hits a button.

The java code you have provided is can be changed as below.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.dynamic_linearlayout);

     TextView epica = (Textview) findViewById(R.id.epica);

     epica.setText("Some text here");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I thought to add a TextSwitcher. 
But now the program gives me a new error: cant resolve -TextSwitcherActivity-

public View makeView() {

                //Create text view
                TextView t = new TextView (TextSwitcherActivity.this);
                //Set the gravity
                t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER);
                //set displayed size
                t.setTextSize(36);
                return t;